# Creando mi "mini shell" - Error: Segmentation Fault

Tags: c, shell, fgets

Estoy desarrollando un mini shell para una práctica de la universidad y me topo con un error que no he conseguido solucionar ya que segun he entendido buscando en google mi error, es un error que te puede salir por causas varias.
A ver si alguien ve por qué me da el error. Por un momento pensé que podía ser por un mal uso del `fgets` [y quité el `line = fgets`... dejando solo el `fgets(.....);`] pero no me sirvió lo que creí que sería una solución.

Este es el error que me da el debugger en la linea del

```
"line = fgets(line, MAX_LINE, stdin);"
```

Más abajo os dejo el código de la función que lo usa con su explicación.

> Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
>   __GI__IO_getline_info (fp=fp@entry=0x7ffff7dd4640 <_IO_2_1_stdin_>, buf=buf@entry=0x0, n=510, delim=delim@entry=10,
>   extract_delim=extract_delim@entry=1, eof=eof@entry=0x0) at
>   iogetline.c:86 86 iogetline.c: No existe el archivo o el directorio.

```
#define PROMPT "$"                                              //declaramos el PROMPT que utilizaremos
#define MAX_LINE 512                                            //declaration of a variable that contains the max number of bits to read

/**
*read_line is a function that recibes a pointer as a parameter
*and returns the same pointer.
*This function prints the PROMPT,cleans the buffer and
*reads a line from the console.
*/
char *read_line (char *line) {
    printf("%s", PROMPT);
    if (fflush (stdout) != 0)
        printf ("the buffer hasn't been cleaned correctly");
    line = fgets(line, MAX_LINE, stdin);
    if (line == NULL)
        printf ("the line hasn't been read correctly or there was anything to read");
    return line;
}

int main() {
    char *line;
    while(read_line(line)) {
    execute_line(line);
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿cómo has declarado el buffer que le pasas a `read_line`? Me refiero al parámetro `line`.

Comment: Coincido con eferion. Faltan datos. ¿ Como has declarado `PROMPT`, `MAX_LINE`, y la propia `line` ?

Comment: @ eferion - Como char *line


@ Trauma :

#define PROMPT "$"                                              //declaramos el PROMPT que utilizaremos
#define MAX_LINE 512                                            //declaration of a variable that contains the max number of bits to read.    Perdon por el formato. Es la primera vez que publico algo en stack overflow.

Comment: Por favor, en lugar de en los comentarios, edita tu pregunta original (y el código que muestras) para que se vean claramente los datos que se te han solicitado. Así facilitas futuras búsquedas.

Comment: Hecho. He agregado las declaraciones iniciales y el main en el que se declara el char *line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El fallo está claro.

```
char *line;
```

Estas declarando un `puntero` que apunta a algo, no sabemos que.

Cambialo por

```
char line[MAX_LINE];
```

y todo debería ir bien.

En C, un código del tipo `char NOMBRE[123]` lo que hace es **reservar memoria para un grupo de 123 elementos, cada uno de los cuales es un char**; pueden ser `char` o `int` o cualquier otro tipo.

Una curiosidad de lo anterior es que, por decirlo de alguna forma, la expresión anterior *devuelve* un puntero; de echo, un `char *` y un `char[]` son **intercambiables** entre si. Es por ello que puedes seguir llamando a tu función `read_line` con el mismo argumento, aunque hayas cambiado su tipo.

Cambiando un poco el tema, el `Segmentation Fault` que te muestra, indica que has intentado acceder a memória **fuera** de tu alcance. Normalmente, memória que no pertenece a tu proceso. En este caso, al hacer `char *line;`, el puntero resultante apuntaba a *alguna lugar desconocido*, que muy difícilmente estaría a tu disposición.